# How call a web user control in client web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm pretty new to SharePoint but am trying to get the hang of it. What I have been doing is creating a Provider Hosted app.However what I want to start doing is creating user controls and wrapping those up in SharePoint web parts.How can i do that please?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean real .ascx controls (i.e. user controls) or controls class (i.e. Web control, that's two different things) you can do that as you would with any Web application (I assume you want to host your controls in the ASP.NET Web application part of your provider-hosted App).

Once your controls are ready, just use them in the pages of the Web app of the provider-hosted part of your App.

Then, as these pages are viewed as iframes from the Client Web part, you're done!

Comment: Thanks  Evariste.I prepare my user control .ascx and I just want to call it from the client web part that I've created.I need to do that programmatically.how can I do that please??

Comment: Your Client Web part is basically nothing else than an IFrame pointing to a page of your Web application (Web application = ASP.NET WebApp part of your project = the "provider-hosted" part of your App). When you create your Client Web part, it necessarly points to a given .aspx page (let's say "home.aspx"). Your .ascx control must embedded into that "home.aspx".